# method to find if the android os is updated or not else finding the date of os installed in the device

Tags: android, android-studio, operating-system, android-os-handler, android-update-sdk

Am working on a project where i have different functions that works based on 
if the device has only unupdated OS(no OS updates had happened in the device) or
if the current OS is an updated version (user had updated OS in the working device).
I looked for some functions in Android.OS..BuildVERSION class. But i couldn't find any.

Is there any functions or flags in android development to check this?
If this is not possible is there a way to find the date of OS installed in the device (via which i can find if its updated or not)?